# C# - How to Connect and Query From Database and Return a JsonResult

Tags: c#, json, api, razor, model-view-controller

I had a question regarding displaying a table is .cshtml with controllers and views. I am attempting to return a JsonResult within my ItemController.cs and am wondering how I can reach my database and return the data based on a query.

```
query = Select * from myFunction(ID)
using SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("connectionString")
       {
           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn)
           {
                sqlConn.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
```

Is this the general setup for connecting to my database? I attempted this but my dt variable showed as {}. Also, after this, to return an MVC JsonResult, I use:

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }
        string json = serializer.Serialize(rows);
        return new JsonResult { Data = json, ContentType = "application/json" };
```

Is there a better way to do this/where could I have gone wrong with the connection above?

Thanks!

Comment: can you please elaborate: query = Select * from myFunction(ID) 
e.g. what is myFunction(ID) ?

Comment: Use web api to query JSON rather than MVC...

Answer (score 0):

this is low-level programming and not recommend.
I recommended using Entity framework, then use [newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) for serialization.

```
public ActionResult GetAll()
{
    using (var db=new YourModel())
    {
     List<YourType> res=db.tabelX.Where(x=>condition).ToList();
     string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
     //or
     return Json(res, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```